# iOS/Firebase - Stripe Connect Account Verification

Tags: stripe-payments

I've created Connected Accounts using Stripe Connect. The account is created, however, it is restricted due to:

INFORMATION NEEDED
Identity document
Owner's additional document

After messing around, I realised if I just go back and mess around with the settings I am then prompted to verify the account. Is there a way in which I can always demand verification when users sign up? I've looked at the documents, but they have not been much help to me.

This is my code:

```
exports.createConnectAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var data = req.body
  var email = data.email
  var response = {}
  stripe.accounts.create(
    {
      object: 'account',
      type: 'express',
      country: 'GB',
      business_type: 'individual',
      email: email,
      capabilities: {
          card_payments: {
            requested: true,
          },
          transfers: {
            requested: true,
          },
        },
    },
      function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Couldn't create stripe account: " + err)
          return res.send(err)
      }
      console.log("ACCOUNT: " + account.id)
      response.body = {success: account.id}
      return res.send(response)
      return admin.firestore().collection('vendors').doc(user.uid).set({account_id: account.id});
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code specifically creates Express accounts with the `card_payments` and `transfers` capabilities. In order for those capabilities to be active you'd need your user to provide additional information.

You can use the [Account Links API](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link) to redirect your users to a Stripe hosted onboarding form which will collect all of this for you.

Comment: I am using the Stripe hosted onboarding already, I'm trying to find a way to enable verification always.